# Laravel 5.2 web middleware in auth controller causes csrf token mismatch

Tags: ajax, laravel, token, csrf, vue.js

Can someone explain me the following behavior, when i enable my routes (login, homepage etc) like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    ....
});
```

A Ajax login modal is working correctly, however when i try the following (enabling middleware in the controllers) which i prefer working with:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('web');
    }
    ...
}

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('web');
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    ...
}
```

A TokenMismatchException is trown in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67.
To my knowledge there shouldn't be a difference in those two approaches, what am i doing wrong here?

csrf token setup:

Base layout:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

modal js:

```
var options = {
  emulateJSON: true,
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're not running the **web** middleware twice?

Comment: I can confirm, when i remove the middleware web from the authcontroller construct function it returns no mismatch but succes and no session is created.

Comment: In Laravel 5.2 the `web` middleware is automatically applied to all routes in `routes.php` so you shouldn't apply the `web` middleware again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give You working example, take from there ideas that will help You:

app/Http/routes.php:

```
// all routes that start with: "/auth" are not filtered by any middleware
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'AuthController@index']);
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'auth.attempt', 'uses' => 'AuthController@attempt']);
    Route::delete('/', ['uses' => 'AuthController@destroy']);
    Route::any('destroy', ['as' => 'auth.destroy', 'uses' => 'AuthController@destroy']);
});

// all routes that start with: "/billing" will be handled by this group (prefix => 'billing')
// all controllers inside this route group are located in 'Billing' namespace
// all routes in this group are pre-checked by middleware 'HasAccessToBilling'
Route::group(['prefix' => 'billing', 'namespace' => 'Billing', 'middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\HasAccessToBilling']], function()
{
    Route::any('/', ['as' => 'billing', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);

    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'billing.profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@index']);

    // TARIFFS
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'tariffs'], function() {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@index']); // showing page with tariffs paginated 
        Route::get('all', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.all', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@all']); // listing all tariffs with json (see controller)

        Route::get('create', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.create', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@create']); // create form
        Route::post('/', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.store', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@store']); // creating

        Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.edit', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@edit']); // edit form
        Route::post('{id}', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.update', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@update']); // updating

        Route::get('{id}/activate', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.activate', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@activate']); // active = 1
        Route::get('{id}/suspend', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.suspend', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@suspend']); // active = 0
        Route::get('{id}/delete', ['as' => 'billing.tariffs.delete', 'uses' => 'TariffsController@delete']); // deleted = 1
    });
```

app/Http/Middleware/HasAccessToBilling.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Library\Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HasAccessToBilling
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::hasAccessTo('billing', $request)) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('auth');
    }
}
```

app/Library/Auth.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Library;

use \App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Crypt;

class Auth
{

    public static function recoverSession(Request $request)
    {
        $rememberToken = $request->cookie('remember-token', null);
        if(is_null($rememberToken)) {
            return null;
        }

        try{
            $rememberToken = Crypt::decrypt($rememberToken);
            $auth = json_decode($rememberToken, true);
            $request->session()->set('auth', $auth);
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex) {}

        return $request->session()->get('auth');
    }

    public static function hasAccessTo($realm, Request $request)
    {
        $auth = $request->session()->get('auth', null);
        if (is_null($auth)) {
            $auth = self::recoverSession($request);
        }

        return (isset($auth['access_to']))?
                in_array($realm, $auth['access_to'])
                : false;
    }
}
```

and finally example controller:

see namespace 'Billing' must be same with folder, otherwise You'll do manual class aliasing in composer.

app/Http/Controllers/Billing/TariffsController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Billing;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Tariff as Model;

class TariffsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Listing records
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $records = Model::paginate();
        return view('billing.tariffs.index', compact('records'));
    }

    /**
     * Listing all tariff plans as json
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function all()
    {
        return $this->ok(Model::all());
    }
```

summary:

1. if You defined middleware in `Route::group` - so no need for calling middleware inside constructor. Idea of route group is to free You from repeating code when writing routes, when giving accesses using middlewares and etc.
2. auth controllers must not be guarded by middleware that denies public access if it's not application for intranet. so You can see that in my routes file I've not defined middleware for "/auth" prefix routes.
3. I don't use csrf tokens (I don't see any reason for it, many years of work I've not ever got the moment where csrf was helpful or saved my life), so I've removed it from `Kernel.php`.